# Execute conditional after each record load

Tags: c#, acumatica

Bit of an Acumatica newb here.

I would like to execute a bit of conditional code after each record load.  I have code running on `Initialize()` to add some custom buttons into a dropdown, but I would like to test each record to see if it contains a valid Phone 1 and Phone 2, to determine whether the buttons should be enabled.

Is there a method I can override that will fire after moving to next / previous records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RowSelected will do that:

```
protected virtual void DACName_RowSelected(PXCache sender, 
                                           PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Reference: [RowSelected](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=13b3e467-b371-4121-a11e-751e49003754)

Comment: For `BusinessAccount` what would the method be called?  I'm getting errors.

Comment: BAccount_RowSelected

Comment: If the button you're trying to change the enabled state is tied to a record in a grid, you'll need to use StateColumn instead, reference: http://blog.zaletskyy.com/enable-disable-button-of-grid-or-pxtoolbarbutton-which-depends-from-value-of-column-in-acumatica

Comment: I believe the `RowSelected` fires before the record actually loads.  Is this correct?  It's throwing errors when I run my conditional.

Comment: You can look up that information in the reference link I have in my answer. The rule of thumb I'm using is that it fires whenever it needs to. The event mechanism is strongly typed and won't throw exception if the DAC declared (BAccount in this case) is used in your graph. It sounds like the errors are in the user code. I would guess these are caused by using variables that haven't been null checked.

Comment: A common pattern is to null check and use the Row property in the Event parameters like this: BAccount bAccount = e.Row as BAccount; if (bAccount == null) return;

Comment: I'm really new to this, like I said.  I'm struggling to find how data fields are related to each other.  For instance, how to get the BAccount contact information from the 'Main Contact' section of the Details tab.  Is there somewhere the data structure is documented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152866/discussion-between-hb-acumatica-and-beardedmogul).